# Reference captured in static variable definition

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int k) {
    static auto bar = [&]{
        std::cout << k << std::endl;
    };
    bar();
}

int main () {
    foo(1); foo(2); foo(3); // output is correct: 1, 2, 3
}
```

Check the function *foo*, an how the static lambda is capturing *k* by reference. This seems to work, and the same is happening with more complicated datatypes rather than *int*.

Is this expected?
Is there any guarantee that the address of *k* will be the same for every invocation of *foo*, or is this **UB**?

Thanks in advance, and sorry if this was previously answered (I did try to find a similar question without success)

Comment: Adam you missed the point by a mile, I'm afraid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It is Undefined Behavior**.

Per Paragraph 5.2.2/4 of the C++11 Standard about function call expressions and the initialization of their parameters:

> [...] **The lifetime of a parameter ends when the function in which it
>   is defined returns**. The initialization and destruction of each parameter occurs within the context of the
>   calling function. [...]

Therefore, your lambda will be storing a reference that becomes dangling as soon as the function call returns.

In this case, implementations are free (and likely) to create function parameters at the same address for each function call, which is probably the reason why you are observing the expected output.

However, this behavior is not mandated by the Standard - therefore, you should not rely on it (if this was the case, your code would be legal because of 3.8/7).

Comment: Great answer! What says 3.8/7?

Comment: @JoséManuel: "*If, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or
released, a new object is created at the storage location which the original object occupied, a pointer that
pointed to the original object, a reference that referred to the original object, or the name of the original
object will automatically refer to the new object and, once the lifetime of the new object has started, can
be used to manipulate the new object, if* [...]" - And what follows are conditions that are satisfied by your example.

Comment: *"Implementations are free (and likely) to create function parameters at the same address for each function call"* - Free of course, but not really *"likely"*, considering that they will usually be passed on the stack (whose top address is very *unlikely* to be the same every time the function is called). Or did you just mean in his example, where it's indeed *"likely"* that the stack pointer won't change between the individual function calls?

Comment: @ChristianRau: Yes, I meant in this example - but you're right, I should have phrased it better. I will edit, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's probably "working" in your example is that the call stack is always lining up the same way.  Try this instead and see if you still get the "expected" output.

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int k) {
    static auto bar = [&]{
        std::cout << k << std::endl;
    };
    bar();
}

void baz(int k) {
    std::cout << "baz: ";
    foo(k);
}

int main () {
    foo(1); baz(2); foo(3);
}
```

Comment: I'm using clang3.2 and g++4.7.2, and your version seems to "work" too.  But I just tried replacing your *foo(k)* with *foo(k+1)* and guess what, now I'm having different outputs from the two compilers :) (clang: 1, 2, 3 and gcc: 1, 3, 3)

Comment: The point is not that what compiler you are using; the point is the behavior is undefined. That means it may work in some case and crash in another. Even worse, it could format your hard drive, stop your oxygen supply or causes other damages.

Comment: I think you need to add [a couple more parameters](http://ideone.com/3B37yt) to get this to work.